# In Hyperledger Fabric NodeJS smart contract, should all parameters be passed as a string?

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

In the `fabric-sample` repository of Hyperledger Fabric, specifically the sample application of commercial paper:

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/commercial-paper/organization/magnetocorp/application/issue.js

There is a line that calls the `issue` function:

```
const issueResponse = await contract.submitTransaction('issue', 'MagnetoCorp', '00001', '2020-05-31', '2020-11-30', '5000000');
```

The last parameter is supposedly an integer but the value `5000000` is passed as a string.

Is this a requirement in writing a NodeJS smart contract in Hyperledger Fabric that all parameters should be passed as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the function parameters must be passed as string.

If you want to pass a JSON to a function you can stringify your data and parse it inside the method.

For example:

```
data = "{\"field1\":\"value1\",\"field2\":\"value2\"}"
var response = await contract.submitTransaction('myFunction', data);
```

And then in your chaincode

```
async myFunction(ctx, data){
    data = JSON.parse(data);

    //... your logics
}
```